# Removing a line from a text document

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently making a script for school work that will have many functions but the one I am stuck on is the remove function.
Basically, what it needs to do is remove a line that the user desires from the 10 lines that there are (We can only allow 10 lines written.
so for example, if the document has:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and I try and remove 8, it would rewrite like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
9
10
```

My current code is here.

```
    elif action1 == '2':
    linetoremove = input('What line would you like to remove? (1 up to 10)')
    with open('highscore.txt', 'r') as fin:
        data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
    with open('highscore.txt', 'w') as fout:
        fout.writelines(data[int(linetoremove)]:)
```

Removes line 1 fine, but any number above will remove all numbers below.
I know that such removing should happen, but I cannot find a way of doing it so only 1 line is removed.

Thanks
Conn

Comment: Note that `data[int(linetoremove)]:` should be `data[int(linetoremove):]`, else your code raises a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays (list and tuple) in python start with index 0, not 1.  That is why your code **seems** to succeed in removing first line when user enters "1".  As it is written, your code only prints line indexed by `linetoremove`.

```
linetoremove = input('What line would you like to remove? (1 up to 10)')
with open('highscore.txt', 'r') as fin:
    data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
del data[int(linetoremove)-1]
with open('highscore.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(data)
```

You could also verify the value entered.

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` to iterate over each line of text and also get its position in the file:

```
with open('highscore.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(data):
        if line_number != int(linetoremove):
            fout.write(line)
```

Comment: @ConnB-M You defined `data` in your question... `data = fin.read()`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be asking for the answer to homework on here but I'm feeling kind! Not the most efficient or fastest, but I thought it would show you the steps the best!

```
def removeLine(line, file):
    f1 = open(file, 'rb').readlines() #Creates a list of the lines in the file, automatically closes file
    try:
        del f1[line-1] #Attempt to delete the line at index
    except:
        print 'Line %s does not exist in %s'%(line, file) #Print and return if it cannot
        return
    f2 = open(file, 'wb') #open new instance of the file in write mode
    for i in f1:
        f2.write(i) #write to the file
    f2.close() #Close file

removeLine(5, 'data')
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand why your code isn't working, you may want to read up on [list slicing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation).

Suppose the user enters '4' as the line number to remove, this results in sending the following slice to your `writelines`.

```
data[4:]
```

We can see what this does with the following example.

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
data[4:] # [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

In short, it returns a list of all values in `data` with index greater than or equal to 4. (Note that the first element has index 0.)

This can be combined with a complementary slice to perform a remove-like operation.

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
data[:3] + data[4:] # [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Note that I called this a remove-like operation because it's creating a new list rather than editing an existing one. To fix your code, you could do something like:

```
index = int(linetoremove) - 1
fout.writelines(data[:index] + data[index+1:])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
del_line = input('What line would you like to remove (1 up to 10)? ')
lines = open('highscore.txt').readlines()
open('highscore.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[del_line:-1])
```